# Remove rows equal in two different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, rows

I have two numpy arrays, A and B, where A is bigger than B.

```
A = [ 1 0 0, 2 0 0, 3 0 0, 4 0 0, 5 0 0]
B = [ 2 0 0, 5 0 0]
```

I need to create another array, C, which contains all rows in A with the exception of those contained in B:

```
C = [1 0 0, 3 0 0, 4 0 0]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Is each element in the list an array? (e.g. `(1,0,0)`)

Comment: i'm a beginner in pyhon.. i can tell you A and B are arrays, and the shape of A is 5x2 and the shape of B is 2x3.. can this info help you to understand my dataset and my question?

Comment: @Sbobby if you just run 'A' as a command, and copy and paste the output into your question, and do the same with 'B', that should help us to understand your data better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the order and your array doesn't contain duplicates you could do the following.

```
A = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
B = [200, 500]

C = list(set(A) - set(B))
```

Otherwise, you could iterate over A and exclude all items that are present in B. I created set_b as it is faster to check if something is present inside a set.

```
A = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
B = [200, 500]
set_b = set(B)

C = [item for item in A if item not in set_b]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in1d`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,0,0], [2,0,0], [3,0,0], [4,0,0], [5,0,0]])
b = np.array([[2,0,0],[5,0,0]])
c = a[~np.in1d(a[:,0].astype(int), b)]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [3 0 0]
 [4 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
C = np.array([x for x in A if x not in B])
```

By the way, I don't quite understand the spaces beween numbers.